# Elastic Search Conflict with Spark Connector, rest high level client no such field error

Tags: apache-spark, elasticsearch, nebula-graph

I am using elasticsearch version 7.9.2, and it is conflicting with nebula spark connector, a spark connector for nebula graph. I have seen cases where spark conflicts with elasticsearch, but with no existing solution.

```
Failed to instantiate [org.elasticsearch.client.RestHighLevelClient]: Factory method 'restHighLevelClient' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: INSTANCE
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:185)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:653)
    ... 47 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: INSTANCE
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.conn.PoolingNHttpClientConnectionManager$InternalAddressResolver.<init>(PoolingNHttpClientConnectionManager.java:619)
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.conn.PoolingNHttpClientConnectionManager.<init>(PoolingNHttpClientConnectionManager.java:165)
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.conn.PoolingNHttpClientConnectionManager.<init>(PoolingNHttpClientConnectionManager.java:149)
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.conn.PoolingNHttpClientConnectionManager.<init>(PoolingNHttpClientConnectionManager.java:121)
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.client.HttpAsyncClientBuilder.build(HttpAsyncClientBuilder.java:668)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.elasticsearch.client.RestClientBuilder.createHttpClient(RestClientBuilder.java:219)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.elasticsearch.client.RestClientBuilder.build(RestClientBuilder.java:191)
    at org.elasticsearch.client.RestHighLevelClient.<init>(RestHighLevelClient.java:287)
    at org.elasticsearch.client.RestHighLevelClient.<init>(RestHighLevelClient.java:279)
    at com.bybit.byassets.collection.config.ElasticSearchConfig.restHighLevelClient(ElasticSearchConfig.java:54)
    at com.bybit.byassets.collection.config.ElasticSearchConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$e050e7f6.CGLIB$restHighLevelClient$0(<generated>)
    at com.bybit.byassets.collection.config.ElasticSearchConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$e050e7f6$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$43cd2bed.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:244)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:331)
    at com.bybit.byassets.collection.config.ElasticSearchConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$e050e7f6.restHighLevelClient(<generated>)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:154)
    ... 48 common frames omitted
```

I have tried shading the nebula spark connector jar, but the error still persists. Any help is appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This looks similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21622885/java-lang-nosuchfielderror-instance) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69679923/java-lang-nosuchfielderror-instance-only-when-running-on-tomcat).

Could you check all dependencies on `httpClient`, there should be one old version before `INSTANCE` field was introduced, we should exclude that `httpClient`.

Comment: The conflict has been solved, but now there is a new dependency conflict regarding jackson: com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/cfg/MapperBuilder.streamFactory()Lcom/fasterxml/jackson/core/TokenStreamFactory; @7: areturn
  Reason:
    Type 'com/fasterxml/jackson/core/JsonFactory' (current frame, stack[0]) is not assignable to 'com/fasterxml/jackson/core/TokenStreamFactory' (from method signature)

Comment: @sim you could check dependecy with tools like https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/dependencies-analysis.html to see if multiple projects depends on different `jackson`, and if conflic exists, exclude one of them will help you pass this.